# Let $f(x)\in C^2[0,2]$, prove that there exists a $\xi\in(0,2)$ such that $\int_0^2f(x)dx=2f(1)+\frac{f''(\xi)}{3}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a twice continuously differentiable function over $[0,2]$, i.e. $f(x)\in C^2[0,2]$, prove that there exists a $\xi\in(0,2)$ such that
$$\int_0^2f(x)dx=2f(1)+\frac{f''(\xi)}{3}.$$

First, my naive idea is to use Taylor expansion with Lagrange remainder
$$f(x)=f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)+\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(x-1)^2.$$
Then integrate both sides over $[0,2]$ we have that
$$\int_0^2f(x)dx=\int_0^2f(1)dx+\int_0^2f'(1)(x-1)dx+\int_0^2\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(x-1)^2dx=2f(1)+\frac{f''(\xi)}{3}.$$
When I finished writing this, I realized that I was wrong, because in Lagrange remainder, $\xi$ is depend on $x$ and it is not a constant, for different $x$ we get different $\xi$, so we can not deduce that
$$\int_0^2\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(x-1)^2dx=\frac{f''(\xi)}{3}.$$
Then I tried many different ideas and failed until I came up with taylor's theorem with Cauchy remainder
$$f(x)=f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)+\frac{1}{2!}\int_1^x(x-t)^2f''(t)dt.$$
Integrate both sides over $[0,2]$ we have that
$$\int_0^2f(x)dx=2f(1)+\int_0^2\left(\int_1^x(x-t)^2f''(t)dt\right)dx.$$
And
$$\int_0^2\left(\int_1^x(x-t)^2f''(t)dt\right)dx
=\int_0^1\left(\int_1^x(x-t)^2f''(t)dt\right)dx+\int_1^2\left(\int_1^x(x-t)^2f''(t)dt\right)dx.$$
Since
$$\int_0^1\left(\int_1^x(x-t)^2f''(t)dt\right)dx=
-\int_0^1\left(\int_x^1(x-t)^2f''(t)dt\right)dx=-\int_0^1\left(\int_0^t(x-t)f''(t)dx\right)dt=\int_0^1f''(t)\frac{t^2}{2}dt=\int_0^1f''(x)\frac{x^2}{2}dx.$$
Similarly, we have that
$$\int_1^2\left(\int_1^x(x-t)^2f''(t)dt\right)dx=\int_1^2f''(x)\frac{(2-x)^2}{2}dx.$$
Thus we have the following formula
$$\int_0^2f(x)dx=2f(1)+\int_0^1f''(x)\frac{x^2}{2}dx+\int_1^2f''(x)\frac{(2-x)^2}{2}dx.$$
Use this and the first mean value theorem of definite integral, there exists $\xi_1\in(0,1)$ and $\xi_2\in(1,2)$ such that
$$\int_0^1f''(x)\frac{x^2}{2}dx=f''(\xi_1)\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{2}dx=\frac{f''(\xi_1)}{6}.$$
$$\int_1^2f''(x)\frac{(2-x)^2}{2}dx=f''(\xi_2)\int_1^2\frac{(2-x)^2}{2}dx=\frac{f''(\xi_2)}{6}.$$
Since $f''(x)$ is continuous, by the intermediate value theorem there exists $\xi\in(0,2)$ such that
$$\frac{f''(\xi_1)}{6}+\frac{f''(\xi_2)}{6}=\frac{f''(\xi)}{3}.$$
Thus we finish our proof.

**My Question：**
(1) Is there a simple way to prove this exercise?

(2) Whether the formula
$$\int_0^2f(x)dx=2f(1)+\int_0^1f''(x)\frac{x^2}{2}dx+\int_1^2f''(x)\frac{(2-x)^2}{2}dx$$
is a special case of a general integral formula, like the Euler-Maclaurin formula or Trapezoidal rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(answer for the first part) What about if you argue like this: take $R=\int_0^2\frac{f''(\xi(x))}{2}(x-1)^2dx, \xi(x) \in [0,2] $

Let $m=\min_{x \in [0,2]}f''(x), M=\max_{x \in [0,2]}f''(x)$, so $m \le f''(\xi(x)) \le M$

You can multiply with $(x-1)^2/2 \ge 0$ and integrate so you get $m/3 \le R \le M/3$ so by the intermediate value theorem for $f''$, there is $\xi \in [0,2]$ st $R=\frac{f''(\xi)}{3}$ and you are done!

Comment: Oh yeah, why didn't I think of that

Answer (score 3):

The result holds even if $f$ is only assumed to be twice differentiable, the continuity of $f''$ is not needed.

The function
$$
 F(x) = \int_{1-x}^{1+x} f(t) \, dt - 2 x f(1)
$$
is thrice differentiable with $F(0) = F'(0) =F''(0) = 0$ and
$$
 F'''(x) = f''(1+x) + f''(1-x) \, .
$$
Taylor's theorem (with the Lagrange remainder) applied to $F$ gives
$$
 \int_0^2 f(x) \, dx - 2 f(1) = F(1) = \frac{F'''(\eta)}{3!} = \frac 13 \left( \frac{f''(1+\eta)+f''(1-\eta)}{2}\right)
$$
for some $\eta \in (0, 1)$.

(*Remark:* This is similar to what you got as $\frac{f''(\xi_1)}{6}+\frac{f''(\xi_2)}{6}$, but without assuming that $f''$ is continuous or even integrable.)

Since $f''$ has the intermediate value property ([Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))) is
$$
\frac{f''(1+\eta)+f''(1-\eta)}{2} = f''(\xi)
$$
for some $\xi \in [1-\eta, 1+\eta] \subset (0, 2)$, and that completes the proof.

Comment: Very beautiful construction proof.

Comment: $f''$ has Darboux (Intermediate value theorem)  property even if discontinuous so the proof I gave also applies though one has to work with infimum and supremum here, and I agree that the result holds then too; cool proof here though